# Detect whether is the immediate sibling of an element is text or another element in lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I'm using lxml library and Python 2.7 to parse xml files. I need to detect if sibling elements which don't have any text between them. For example in following xml portion:

```
<cross-ref> [t1] </cross-ref> ***some text*** <cross-ref> [t2] </cross-ref>  
<cross-ref> [t3] </cross-ref><cross-ref> [t4] </cross-ref>
```

saying that I detect all elements with cross-ref tags, I need a way which only detects cross-ref elements on second line which second element comes after the first one with no text between them. So I guess something as folloing for loop is needed but obviously this code prints both `[t1]` and `[t3]`

```
for c in cross_refs:
  # detect ***some text*** or do something else here
  if c.getnext().tag == "cross-ref":
     print c.text
```

I need to modify it so the output will be only `[t3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triple nested `if`s in your answer can also be expressed in XPath as follow :

```
following-sibling::node()[1][self::cross-ref]
```

In short, the XPath returns the nearest following sibling *node* only if it is `cross-ref` element. Notice that *node* here means *either text node or element node*. The XPath can be used as follow :

```
for c in cross_refs:
    if c.xpath('boolean(following-sibling::node()[1][self::cross-ref])'):
        print c.text
```

Or you can get only `cross-ref` elements that match this criteria in the first place, if you like :

```
cross_refs = tree.xpath('//cross-ref[following-sibling::node()[1][self::cross-ref]]')
for c in cross_refs:
    print c.text
```

Comment: what is the point of using this code if it doesn't distinguish text and element?the main problem is that I don't want elements with text between them to be detected as siblings.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I mean the following bits 'doesn't distinguish text and element': `following-sibling::node()[1]`, but then the next bits filters further to only `cross-ref` element : `[self::cross-ref]`. So the entire expression returns the next `cross-ref` element if it is directly after the current `cross-ref`, which can then be used to solve the problem you mentioned

Comment: @AliGH: using har07's XPath, you can find the desired elements with no tails using `[elt.text for elt in tree.xpath('//cross-ref[following-sibling::*[1][self::cross-ref]]' if elt.tail is None]`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using tail property. When c.tail is None, then I can say that to elements are attached with no text between them. The code is like this:

```
for c in cross_refs:
    if c.getnext() != None:
        if c.getnext().tag == c.tag:
            if c.tail == None:
                print c.text
```